# Cannot save Shape drawing as Image to Photos with ImageRenderer View

Tags: swift, swiftui, ui-toolkit

I've this View with which I want to let user  draw over an image, and then save the image + drawing as Image in Photos.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DrawView2: View {
    var image: UIImage
    @State var points: [CGPoint] = []
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.addNewPoint(value)
                    }
            )
            .overlay () {
                DrawShape(points: points)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 50) // here you put width of lines
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .clipped()
            }
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        
    }
    
    private func addNewPoint(_ value: DragGesture.Value) {
        // here you can make some calculations based on previous points
        points.append(value.location)
    }
}

struct DrawShape: Shape {
    
    var points: [CGPoint]
    
    // drawing is happening here
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        guard let firstPoint = points.first else { return path }
        
        path.move(to: firstPoint)
        for pointIndex in 1..<points.count {
            path.addLine(to: points[pointIndex])
            
        }
        return path
    }
}

struct DrawHelper: View {
    var image: UIImage
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                
                let drawView = DrawView2(image: image)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, 
                    height: proxy.size.height / 2, alignment: .center)
                
                drawView
                    .cornerRadius(UIConstants.standardCornerRadius)
                
                Button  {
                    let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: drawView)
                    if let image = renderer.uiImage {
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save Mask")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is:
I'm able to draw on the image correctly but it saves only original image. no DrawingShape included in the final saved image.

Screenshot from the Simulator:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i6Gz.jpg)

Saved Image from the Photos:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg1UH.jpg)

Instead of ImageRenderer, I used following method to save the view as Image but it

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        //let targetSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 384)
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried another approach of using Canvas View but found it had the same problem.

```
struct DrawView3: View {
    var image: UIImage
    
    @State var points: [CGPoint] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            
            context.draw(Image(uiImage: image).resizable(), in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
            
            context.stroke(
                DrawShape(points: points).path(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)),
                with: .color(.green),
                lineWidth: 50
                
            )
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.addNewPoint(value)
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    // here you perform what you need at the end
                    
                }
        )
    }
    
    private func addNewPoint(_ value: DragGesture.Value) {
        // here you can make some calculations based on previous points
        points.append(value.location)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I have been snapshotting the original state of the `View` with `ImageRenderer`. When the `View` gets updated with the drawing of the shape, the new state was never passed to `ImageRenderer`.

Fixed this issue by `@Binding` the `points` var instead of defining it as `@State` inside the view.

```
struct DrawView2: View {
    var image: UIImage
    @Binding var points: [CGPoint]
    var body: some View {
...
    }
}


struct DrawingHelper: View {
...
...

    var body: some View {
     ...
    let drawView = DrawView2(image: image, points: $points)
     ...
    } 


struct DrawHelper: View {
   @State var points: [CGPoint] = []
    var image: UIImage
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                
                let drawView = DrawView2(image: image, points: $points)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, 
                    height: proxy.size.height / 2, alignment: .center)
                
                drawView
                    .cornerRadius(UIConstants.standardCornerRadius)
                
                Button  {
                    let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: drawView)
                    if let image = renderer.uiImage {
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```